# Posting Useful Information

Tags: support, community-wiki

Is there a place where useful information can be posted without actually asking a question?  For example, while doing some research, just prior to asking a question on SuperUser, I found the answer.  It isn't something very obvious or intuitive though, and it'd be nice to post it somewhere, so others (or myself) can find it in the future.  I've seen the check-boxes for the "community wiki," but I've never seen it.  What/Where is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ask the question as if you hadn't found the answer, then answer the question yourself. This behaviour is in fact encouraged.

If you are lucky you may even get an answer that is better than the one you found. But if this does not happen you can accept your own answer after 48 hours.

You should **NOT** make it a wiki, if the question and the answer are good you deserve the up votes.

Comment: Also note there is a time limit on when you can self answer. I think it is 15 minutes or something.

Comment: The time limit @Diago mentioned does no longer exist. I was able to answer questions of mine within seconds just fine.